# How to set the PDDocument as pageable in PDFBox 2.0.0?

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

How to use the pageable function in PDFBox 2.0.0. I did my application using PDFBox 1.8.3. I can able to set the document in Pageable format using PDFBox 1.8.3. But I'm unable to set the document as pageable in 2.0.0

```
PrintJob job = new PrintJob();
job.setPageable(pddocument);
```

Could you please help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **[migration guide](http://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html)** for updating from 1.8 to 2.0.

Your code should look like:

```
job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(pddocument));
```

Note: It is `PDFPageable`, not `PDPageable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
job.setPageable(new PDPageable(pddocument, job));
```

This is, BTW, essentially what `PDDocument.print(PrinterJob, boolean)` already used to do in PDFBox version 1.8.3.